# Javascript Randomly Positioned Div's without overlapping them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, random, overlap

I've been working on a random concept idea of having 6 clouds appear on a page with random comments pulled from a database. That part is easy, however I'm finding it extremely difficult to make sure the 6 clouds don't overlap each other. I've looked into Collision Detection a lot and found that there's no real suitable method of checking for a DIV within a range at X or Y before placing the new "randomly positioned" div on the page. I have my code below which I know is extremely messy right now. I currently have it checking the last DIV with reasonable success but if DIV 1 and DIV 3 for example, have similar X Y positions then It's a problem. Sorry If I'm making no sense.. here's my code and a jsFiddle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;
//var colide = {};
var px = 0;
var py = 0;

var clouds = new Array("cloud1", "cloud2", "cloud3", "cloud4", "cloud5", "cloud6");
var cloudtext = new Array("This is text for cloud 1 :D", "This is text for cloud 2 :D", "This is text for cloud 3 :D", "This is text for cloud 4 :D", "This is text for cloud 5 :D", "This is text for cloud 6 :D");

function makeDiv() {
    if (counter < 6) {
        counter++;

        //var divsize = ((Math.random() * 100) + 50).toFixed();
        //var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
        $newdiv = $('<div class="' + clouds[counter - 1] + '">' + cloudtext[counter - 1] + '<div/>').css({

            'width': '354px',
                'height': '202px'

            //'width': divsize + 'px',
            //'height': divsize + 'px',
            //'background-color': color,
        });

        var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - 354)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - 202)).toFixed();

        while (posy < 180) {
            posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - 202)).toFixed();
        }


        if ((px > posx + 354) || (px < posx - 354)) {
            if ((py > posy + 202) || (py < posy - 202)) {


                //alert(px + ' - ' + posx + ' px(temp) - posx(newdiv) - good to go!');
                py = posy;
                px = posx;
                $newdiv.css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                        'left': posx + 'px',
                        'top': posy + 'px',
                        'display': 'none',
                        'background-image': 'url(http://www.demixgaming.co.uk/cloud/images/Cloud.png)',
                        'text-align': 'center',
                        'line-height': '202px',
                        'color': '#000'
                }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(150).delay(300, function () {
                    makeDiv();
                });
            } else {
                counter--;
                px = posx;
                py = posy;
                makeDiv();
            }
        } else {
            counter--;
            px = posx;
            py = posy;
            makeDiv();
        };

    }
}
makeDiv();
```

});

JS Fiddle - [Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Y4r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm would look something like this; I might have made a mistake though

1. Get the document's height and width *y = docH, x = docW*
2. Subtract the `<div>`'s height and width, *y = y - divH, x = x - divH*
3. Choose random co-ordinates *curX, curY* between *0..x, 0..y*
4. *newX = curX, newY = curY*
5. For each previous `<div>`

   1. Call it's info *prevX, prevY, prevW, prevH*
   2. If *prevX < curX* then *newX = newX + prevW*
   3. If *prevY < curY* then *newY = newY + prevH*
6. Append `<div>` at *newX, newY*
7. Save `<div>` info *curX, curY, divW, divH*
8. If there is another `<div>`, go to step 2.

Comment: Substeps under 5 should be more like `'if (curX > prevX - divW && curX < prevX + divW && curY > prevY - divH && curY < prevY + divH) { pick new position and start checks over }'`

Comment: @ejegg The more items you're adding, the worse an idea it is to "pick new" with random, hence why I tried to make it translate.

Comment: True, but you still only need to move the div if it overlaps in both X and Y - no need to move it if it's just aligned above/below or left/right of an existing div.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I'm still pretty new with Javascript so It's taking me a while to get my head around it. I will re-work my code following the rules of that algorithm and see what I can come up with